# Вместо приложения белый экран на Github Pages. Как это починить?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, github-pages

Опубликовала приложение, написанное на Vue.js, на Github Pages. Ссылка на репозиторий: https://github.com/hokkuistka/marvel.
При открытии сайта по ссылке https://hokkuistka.github.io/marvel/ показывает только белый экран.
Консоль выдает вот такие [ошибки](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTvXe.jpg). Я новичок и не понимаю, как их исправить. Подскажите, что не так?

Comment: Прикладывайте, пожалуйста, текст ошибок и код с ними связанный непосредственно в теле вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`Ошибка 404` - обозначает что файл не найден.**

Согласно [официальной документации](https://cli.vuejs.org/ru/guide/deployment.html#github-pages) вам нужно прописать в конфиге правильный путь к проекту `publicPath`:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/marvel/'
    : '/'
})
```

и соответсвенно билд приложения выполнять так:

```
vue-cli-service build --mode production
```

[Там](https://cli.vuejs.org/ru/guide/deployment.html#github-pages) еще много дополнительной информации, не вижу смысл публиковать ее здесь, так как актуальность может со временем утратиться.

Cейчас файл `js` у вас ищется по пути:

https://hokkuistka.github.io/js/app.a9c438fd.js

а должен был искаться по пути:

https://hokkuistka.github.io/marvel/js/app.a9c438fd.js

*вы можете убедится что вторая ссылка ведет к файлу а первая нет*

В качестве быстрого решения можете поправить html файл вручную, добавив `/marvel` к нужным файлам:

```
<script src="/marvel/js/chunk-vendors.358e40d0.js"></script>
<script src="/marvel/js/app.a9c438fd.js"></script>
```

Так же можете ознакомиться с документацией самого гитхаба о [GitHub Pages](https://docs-github-com.translate.goog/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=ru&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp) необходимо убедится что все перечисленные пункты выполнены правильно.